# Como obtener solo un registro y guardarlo en una variable en php?

Tags: php, php7

Tengo este select en el que quiero obtener el registro con la fecha más reciente de publicacón:

```
   $sql ="select nombre from photos where pubdate = (select max(pubdate) from photos)";
   $consulta= $db->prepare($sql);
   $consulta->execute();
   foreach ($consultaas $fila) {
       $name=$fila['nombre'];
   }
```

En este select solo me devuelve un registro, puedo directamente guardar ese nombre que me devuelve en la
variable como de esta forma:

> $name= $consulta->execute();

Sin necesidad de hacer un foreach o algúna función de iteración para recorrer.

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa, ¿cuál es el problema con ese código?

Comment: Lo que quiero preguntar es si una consulta que devuelve solo un registro si la puedo igualar a una variable sin necesidad de recorrer con foreach,while... y asignarle a la variable el dato que quiero directamente sin tener que hacer algún bucle en concreto, no se si me explico. A no ser que no haya de otra forma que no sea con un foreach....

Comment: ¿Estas usando `MySQLi` o `PDO`?

Comment: Solo nos han dejado usar de momento PDO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si estas usando PDO puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
$result = $db->query($sql);
$result = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

De esta manera seria usando **prepare** y **execute**

```
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
$result = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

eso te devuelve un array indexado por nombre de columna.
Saludos

Comment: y utilizando un `execute` para pasarle los parámetros al sql como se haría ?

Comment: es de la misma manera, he editado mi respuesta para que se vea.